# Can you use formula for viscosity derived from Stokes' law to calculate viscosity of non-Newtonian fluid if constant force is applied?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, non-newtonian-fluids, rheology

I would like to drop a ball into a test tube containing mixed corn starch and water ( in different ratios) and use Stokes law to get the viscosity for the fixed weight of the ball that I used. Would this be a correct method? Thanks.